# Including Adobe AIR/Flash with Application

Tags: java, android, eclipse, flash, air

So I developed an application for Android of which uses an SWF file. Now, I did this within Eclipse instead of using Flash CS6's native AIR libraries and such. Many devices of which downloaded the app are seeing it break because they can't support flash.

How would I go about including something like the AIR Runtime bundled with the application so all users could use the application?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You should propably develop the flash application for example in Flash CC and make the project a mobile one for android and there it converts and makes the project in a .apk file.

Comment: Problem is I already have developed the application. I couldn't just do that in Flash because I used Java and other native features within App Development.

Answer (score 0):

Download the AIR SDK from Adobe. Create an application descriptor that references your SWF file and contains the proper settings for an Android mobile app (all documented on Adobe's developer site). Then use the AIR ADT tool to package it into an AIR app. That's all you should need to do assuming your SWF file is otherwise normal.

Comment: How would I go about using the SDK within Eclipse with my already developed Application?

Comment: Probably the easiest way would be to create an Ant script that did the packaging. There may be other ways, too. Note, I don't know how you are creating the SWF file in Eclipse (I've never done that), you may need to compile with the AIR SDK libraries as well -- but maybe not since AIR is essentially a superset containing Flash, you'll just have to try it.